# How to make default path to the executable file via Blender Python API?

Tags: python

I'm working on render engine which need to select binary executable file for working engine properly but I would like to include that binary executable file inside my addon (e.g.: <my_addon\bin\engine.exe>) and post relative path to that exe file via addon istelf not as "Select path to exe file"-like method. By default for selecting path to exe file is works like this on my addon:

```
exe_bin_dir: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="",
                                             description="",
                                             default=util.switchpath(tempfile.gettempdir())+'/',
```

There is "util.switchpath" not by default, it does mean it takes "switchpath" defined operator from inside "util.py" file and pin here.

So, my question is how to code for make default path to my addon like for example:

```
exe_bin_dir: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="",
                                         description="",
                                         default="./<my_addon/bin/engine.exe>"
```

What am I must overwrite here on three dots?

```
"default=..."
```

Comment: Why would the render engine be an exe file?

Comment: The addon itself is an exporter which export scene and then it will open with that executable file as command line method. Otherwise the addon itself cannot do the job without the exe file.

Comment: You didn’t explain why the render engine needs to be a separate executable file.

Comment: The engine is not exe file. The engine itself binary exe file which has core inside it pre-compiled. My addon is exporter and render scenes via exporter as geometries and naterials and finally render it inside Blender by using that exe file command-line mode.

Comment: What engine are you using that you only have access to as an executable?

Comment: pbrtv4 by matt pharr and wenzel jakob

Comment: That render engine is open source, and is written in C++, as is Cycles. I recommend you look into the possibility of implementing it the same way Cycles is.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want your adodn to select this file automatically, but also to let the user define an other path if they want to ? Why don't you hardcode the path and use a string property path that's empty by default ? if the user changes this path, then use this one, else use the hardcoded one ?

Comment: Yes, I would like addon will automatically search that exe file and use them by default not user changes the direction. Because I will put exe file by default inside to "bin" direction of the addon.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this method:

```
curentDirectory = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


class EngineRenderSettings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

exe_bin_dir: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="",
                                         description="",
                                         default=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(curentDirectory), 'bin'),
                                         subtype='DIR_PATH')
```